# Redirecting from one UIViewController to another when clicking a UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I'm trying to build a reusable code that I will be able to use in several places in my IOS application.
What it does is to create a table that each cell in it has several UIButtons. When clicking on a button, the View needs to be redirected to another ViewController and show data related to that button (user ID for example).
Because I want this code to be reusable, I've created a UIViewController that the other views will inherit from. My ViewController programmatically builds the UITableView and cells and populates everything inside.
The only thing I can't figure out is how to redirect the view to the next when touching the UIButton. I'm trying to do that without segues because I want this as a self sustained component and without the need to 'play' with storyboards and push the same segues repeatedly in different places.
**Any suggestion will be appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code when hitting the button

```
ViewController *obj = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Where ViewController is the controller you are going to.

If you want to pass data just set a variable in the ViewController your going to on the button click. Use the code above with the line below before the push

```
obj.userId = @"UserId1";
```

Comment: Thanks!
I don't have a nib file so I used it with UIStoryboard:

UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ViewController* obj = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];